# Learning FFmpeg: video from webcam, audio from headset mic

Tags: ffmpeg

I've read through the 62-page FFmpeg doc. It's a great reference but not so good a teacher for someone new to video production. I joined the mail list but there seems to be no traffic on it. I hope here is where I can learn what I need to be productive.

Using `ffmpeg -devices` shows me that my Logitech c925e webcam is video0 and video1, but the command `ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy` found on several web pages results in this output:

> Unrecognized option 'list_devices'. Error splitting the argument list:
> Option not found

Using

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -i pulse -c:v copy -c:a aac output.mp4
```

results in:

> pulse: No such file or directory

How do I specify the webcam and headset mic to record a video?

Comment: `dshow` only applies on Windows. Are you on linux?

Comment: I apologize. Yes, I run linux and I had learned that dshow is only for Windows. I've saved a number of web pages with example for various ffmpeg tasks and most don't specify that they apply to one OS only.